SSAS Add a rolemember using Powershell
I'm trying to add rolemembers for a Tabular database in SSAS using powershell.  I can add a role using:
    $tabularName = Tabulardatabase
    $json = @"
    {   
        "create":{   
           "parentObject":{   
              "database":"$($tabularName)"  
           },  
           "role":{  
              "name":"kt1",  
              "modelPermission":"read",
              "members":[   
                 {  
                    "memberName": "us\\xyz"
                 }
              ]
           }  
        }  
     }
    "@
    $connectionString = "Data Source=$SSASServer;Initial Catalog=$tabularName"
    Invoke-ASCmd -ConnectionString $connectionString -Query $json

I see that alter is a valid parameter but I cannot get it to work.
I tried this code for alter:
    $json = @"
    {   
        {   
       "alter":{   
          "object":{   
             "database":"Tabulardatabase"  
               
          },  
          "role":{   
             "name":"kt1"  
          },
          "members": {
           "type": "array",
           "items": { "us\\ABC"
                    }
         }
       }  
    }
    }
     
    "@


but I am getting -
Unrecognized JSON property: parentObject. Check path.
